# Why is Cl2-P-O-Cl an unfavourable structure for POCl3?

Tags: resonance, lewis-structure, formal-charge

Why is the structure $\ce{(Cl)2P - O - Cl}$ unfavourable compared to the two structures in the picture?

The latter in the picture and the one I stated both have zero formal charge, so I don't really see why the structure I made isn't favourable.

[image: 1]

Comment: Both O and Cl favour making bonds to P than to each other.

Comment: Is there a quick way to explain this? If not no problem, thank you for answering.

Comment: Compare their electronegativities ( P 2.1 Cl 3.0 O 3.5, Al approx.) and eventually enthalpies of bond formation, if available. Compounds with Cl-O bonds are energy rich.

Comment: Additionally, there would be reducing P(+III) next to oxidizing O-Cl. Water and fire in the same place.